# Why is my installation of latest Java OpenJDK failing?

Tags: cygwin, openjdk

I am trying to build the latest Java OpenJDK on Windows 11 from source using Cygwin, from the Git repo https://github.com/openjdk/loom

Following the instructions in the README.md there, I see

```
If you are eager to try out building the JDK, these simple steps works most of the time. They assume that you have installed Git (and Cygwin if running on Windows) and cloned the top-level JDK repository that you want to build.

Get the complete source code:
git clone https://git.openjdk.java.net/jdk/

Run configure:
bash configure

If configure fails due to missing dependencies most of the time it prints a suggestion on how to resolve the situation on
your platform. Follow the instructions, and try running `bash configure`
again.
```

I am doing

```
bash configure --enable-absolute-paths-in-output
```

(Tried with and without that --enable flag)

I have Visual Studio community installed, with C++ for desktop development add-in installed.

It gets to the following, then fails.

Any guidance?

```
configure: Using default toolchain microsoft (Microsoft Visual Studio)
configure: Found Visual Studio installation at /cygdrive/c/progra~1/mib055~1/2022/Community using well-known name
configure: Warning: None of vc/bin/amd64/vcvars64.bat vc/bin/x86_amd64/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat             vc/auxiliary/build/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat vc/auxiliary/build/vcvars64.bat were found, Visual Studio installation not recognized. Ignoring
configure: Found Visual Studio installation at /cygdrive/c/progra~1/mib055~1/2022/Community using well-known name
configure: Warning: None of vc/bin/amd64/vcvars64.bat vc/bin/x86_amd64/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat             vc/auxiliary/build/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat vc/auxiliary/build/vcvars64.bat were found, Visual Studio installation not recognized. Ignoring
configure: error: Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation
configure exiting with result code 1
```

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: According to the instructions, you need to build the Windows installation using Cygwin

Comment: @VinnyGray - What instructions exactly? Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 doesn’t use Cygwin at in my experience.  Why don’t you just install OpenJDK directly to the Windows environment instead of Cygwin?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I am trying to build the latest from source, using the git repo https://git.openjdk.java.net/jdk/. I updated the original post

Comment: Okay. So do the files that it's complaining about really not exist?